# ASP.NET webforms without javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Due to a security requirement all browsers that will run a web application we need to create must have all client side scripting disabled. So that means no Javascript.
Unfortunately Web Forms make quite some use of Javascript. The login control works without Javascript, but a button does not (it calls the Javascript function __doPostback()).
So to make it work we'd need to program all the forms by hand (the ASP Classic, or PHP method). But I was wondering if there is a framework available for ASP.NET that offers the normal ASP.NET controls (treeview, gridview, etc) with all the functoinality they have, but that doesn't use Javascript and doesn't require the programmer to program massive amounts of logic?

**Update:**
For clarification, I know ASP.NET MVC is an option that will help a bit, but it won't give me a nice GridView. So I'm wondering if there is a 100% functional, 100% no-javascript replacement for the standard ASP.NET controls.

Thanks.

**Update2:**
It's been a while and I never found the exact answer I was looking for. Probably because what I want doesn't exist. So I'll go for ASP.NET MVC which is the next best thing.

Comment: That is some very tight security. Why not simply add the url for the web application as a trusted site, or a custom security site that allows javascript? Javascript in itself is so limited it doesn't pose much of a threat, particularly when all you're using is your own code (with no x-site scripts)

Comment: Sorry you didn't get the answer you were looking for. This was a good question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) is probally the closest you'd get. You can use it to build a site without javascript. It is very different from Web forms

Answer (score 4):

Many of the stock controls will be problematic.  They just depend too heavily on Javascript.  You do have some options, though:

- ASP.Net MVC should give you a bit more control over your html
- You can build your own replacement WebForms control library that doesn't rely on javascript to provide alternatives for controls that do.